# Does number of same expressions in Angular JS HTML affect performance?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, dom, angularjs-scope

Consider an Angular HTML Partial:

```
<div>
  <p>
    <span ng-if="abc.def !== 'someValue'"></span>
    <span ng-if="abc.def === 'someValue'"></span>
  </p>

  <ul ng-if="abc.def !== 'someValue'">
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
  </ul>

  <div ng-if="abc.def !== 'someValue'" 
    ng-class="{'alternative-list': abc.def !=='someValue'}">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>

  <div ng-class="{'class-a': abc.def !== 'someValue', 'class-b': abc.def === 'someValue'}"></div>

</div>
```

- Does having more angular expressions doing the same check, have a bad effect on performance?
- Or does Angular **pre-calculates** and effectively does one-time parsing only for all `ng-ifs`?

Could not find this in the documentation.

Comment: If you had one of them instead execute a function, and then counted how many times that function gets executed, you'd have a pretty clear answer.

Comment: as always, the more work you do, the longer it takes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no.

You can find code for ng-if here: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/ngIf.js

As you can see, it adds `$scope.$watch()` for expression stored in `ng-if` tag. The `$watch` method refers to `$parse` method which stores expression in dictionary `expression => parsedExpression`, as you can see here:
https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/parse.js

Thats all it does related to caching. You can also see example here:
http://jsfiddle.net/zxfje53h/1/

Answer (score 0):

Every time you use a directive and angular encounters it using the angular html compiler it will run the directives compile function get back the link function from that and will call the link function with a scope.  There is no real sharing of the information parsed between the directives as far as I know no such optimization exists in the framework for caching the parsed/processed values since after parsing it needs to apply the particular scope to the returned function from parsing I'm not sure how much benefit having a cache of the expressions/parse functions would help.